# load rjs file by clicking submit tag in Rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to load a modal dialog box by clicking submit tag. but when I click on the button, it directly went to page without going to rjs file and did not render partial.
following is my code.

```
<span style="text-align: right">
<% form_tag "/calendar/dia_cal_view" do %>
<%= collection_select("event", "trainer_id", @trainers , :id, :name, {:prompt => true}) %>
<%= submit_tag "search" %>
<%end%>
</span>
```

controller code:

```
def dia_cal_view

@month = (params[:month] || (Time.zone || Time).now.month).to_i
@year = (params[:year] || (Time.zone || Time).now.year).to_i
@shown_month = Date.civil(@year, @month)
@trainers=Trainer.all 
@first_day_of_week = 1
 if session[:dia_Serach].nil?
    if (defined? (params[:event][:trainer_id]))
        session[:dia_Serach]=(params[:event][:trainer_id])
        #@@id=(params[:event][:trainer_id])
        @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week, :conditions=>["trainer_id = ?",session[:dia_Serach]])            
    else
        @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week)              
    end
else
    @event_strips = Event.event_strips_for_month(@shown_month, @first_day_of_week, :conditions=>["trainer_id = ?",session[:dia_Serach]])            
end 
 end
```

dia_cal_view.js.rjs

```
page.replace_html 'search_result', :partial => 'cal_view'

page<< "$j ('#search_result_dialog').dialog({
    title: 'calendar',
    modal: true,
    width: 500,
   height: 500,
    close: function(event, ui) { $j ('#search_result_dialog').dialog('destroy') }

});"
```

_cal_view.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "event_calendar" %>
<%= event_calendar %>
```

The problem is that rjs file did not work. It did not  go to rjs file. what should I do for this? plz help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all your form is submitted as a html and not as a rjs request.
You first need to change that to rjs request, change this line

```
<% form_tag "/calendar/dia_cal_view" do %>
```

use

> remote_form_tag

or option

> remote = true

depending on your rails version

It should work then

Comment: I am using rails 2.3.8 and I add remote_form_tag. but then it wil show 500 internal server error.